# Converting multiple lists into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list

I created those lists to store things i generate over a for loop which is shown a bit further down.

```
neutralScore = []
lightPosScore = []
middlePosScore = []
heavyPosScore = []
lightNegScore = []
middleNegScore = []
heavyNegScore = []
```

Here comes the loop

```
score = float
convertStringToInt = get_sent_score_comp_df.apply(lambda x: float(x))
for score in convertStringToInt:
    if score <= 0.09 and score >= -0.09:
        neutralScore.append(score)
    elif score >= 0.091 and score <= 0.49:
        lightPosScore.append(score)
```

I want to save my sentiments into those lists, then join them to be able to convert them into a DataFrame to store them in a MySQl DB.
Is there an elegant way to do this?

```
scores = pandas.DataFrame(data=neutralScore).append(lightPosScore, middlePosScore, heavyPosScore).append(
        lightNegScore,
        middleNegScore,
        heavyNegScore).columns = ['heavyPosScore', 'middlePosScore', 'lightPosScore', 'neutralScore', 'lightNegScore', 'middleNegScore', 'heavyNegScore']
```

I know, that declaring the list of columns needs to be done separately, but until now the code looks like that.

So far I tried this and it doesn't work since it returns:

> Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'list'> was passed

which is understandable, but I can´t think of a way to solve the problem right now.

Comment: You should mayby use ```zip```: ```pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lightPosScore, middlePosScore, heavyPosScore)), columns=['lightPosScore', 'middlePosScore', 'heavyPosScore'])```

Comment: I tried to get that running in one go:```scores = pandas.DataFrame(list(zip(lightPosScore, middlePosScore, heavyPosScore, neutralScore, lightNegScore, middleNegScore, heavyNegScore))).columns=cols``` and got that ```Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 7 elements``` i defined cols as all the colums i want to have in an []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from question how you want your final dataframe to look like. But I would do something like:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd    
>>> data = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=10)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['score'])    
>>> df
|    |     score |
|---:|----------:|
|  0 | -0.440304 |
|  1 | -0.597293 |
|  2 | -1.80229  |
|  3 | -1.65654  |
|  4 | -1.14571  |
|  5 | -0.760086 |
|  6 |  0.244437 |
|  7 |  0.828856 |
|  8 | -0.136325 |
|  9 | -0.325836 |

>>> df['neutralScore'] = (df.score <= 0.09) & (df.score >= -0.09)
>>> df['lightPosScore'] = (df.score >= 0.091) & (df.score <= 0.49)
```

And similar for the columns `'heavyPosScore', 'middlePosScore', 'lightNegScore', 'middleNegScore', 'heavyNegScore'`.

```py
>>> df
|    |      score | neutralScore   | lightPosScore   |
|---:|-----------:|:---------------|:----------------|
|  0 | -0.475571  | False          | False           |
|  1 |  0.109076  | False          | True            |
|  2 |  0.809947  | False          | False           |
|  3 |  0.595088  | False          | False           |
|  4 |  0.832727  | False          | False           |
|  5 | -1.30049   | False          | False           |
|  6 |  0.245578  | False          | True            |
|  7 |  0.0998278 | False          | True            |
|  8 |  0.20592   | False          | True            |
|  9 |  0.372493  | False          | True            |
```

You can then easily filter on the type of score like this:

```py
>>> df[df.lightPosScore]
|    |    score | neutralScore   | lightPosScore   |
|---:|---------:|:---------------|:----------------|
|  0 | 0.415629 | False          | True            |
|  2 | 0.104852 | False          | True            |
|  4 | 0.39739  | False          | True            |
```

**Edit**

To have one `rating` colmn, first define a function to give your ratings and apply that to your `score` column:

```py
>>> def get_rating(score):
      if score <= 0.09 and score >= -0.09:
          return 'neutralScore'
      elif score >= 0.091 and score <= 0.49:
          return 'lightPosScore'
      else:
          return 'to be implemented'

>>> df['rating'] = df['score'].apply(get_rating)
>>> df
|    |      score | rating            |
|---:|-----------:|:------------------|
|  0 | -0.190816  | to be implemented |
|  1 |  0.495197  | to be implemented |
|  2 | -1.20576   | to be implemented |
|  3 | -0.711516  | to be implemented |
|  4 | -0.0606396 | neutralScore      |
|  5 |  0.0452575 | neutralScore      |
|  6 |  0.154754  | lightPosScore     |
|  7 | -0.506285  | to be implemented |
|  8 | -0.896066  | to be implemented |
|  9 |  0.523198  | to be implemented |
```

Comment: Looks like a neat solution. If i want it to look like that what is in my head ist would be score in one column and the next one would read "rating" with the matching category
Like: score: 0,412 | rating: middlePositiveScore

Comment: That looks great. Thank you for your help. I´ll will stick with that :)